# Guardar Cabecera Detalle EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicacion donde necesito guardar una factura, donde consta el cliente que y el detalle de dicha factura, aqui el codigo:

```
using(Context context = new Context())
{
    Cliente cliente;
    if (clienteActual != consumidorFinal)
    {
        cliente = new Cliente()
        {
            Nombre = txtClienteNombre.Text.Trim(),
            Cedula = txtClienteCedula.Text.Trim(),
            Status = Status.Activo
        };
        context.Cliente.Add(cliente);
    }
    else
    {
        cliente = ClienteActual;
    }

    context.Cliente.Attach(cliente);
    cliente.CabeceraFactura = new List<CabeceraFactura>();
    CabeceraFactura cabeceraFactura = new CabeceraFactura()
    {
        Fecha = DateTime.Today,
        Status = Status.Activo,
        Cliente = cliente
    };

    cabeceraFactura.DetalleFactura = new List<DetalleFactura>();
    decimal total = 0;

    foreach (DetalleFactura entry in detalleFacturaBindingSource)
    {
        total += (entry.PrecioUnitario * entry.Cantidad);
        cabeceraFactura.DetalleFactura.Add(entry);
    }

    cabeceraFactura.Total = total;
    cliente.CabeceraFactura.Add(cabeceraFactura);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
}
```

el problema es que me salta

> **System.InvalidOperationException**:
>   An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar `.Add()` y `.Attach()` sobre el mismo objeto ya que lo agregaría dos veces al `ChangeTracker` y por lo tanto falla (con el error que indicas). Por lo tanto:

```
if (clienteActual != consumidorFinal)
{
    cliente = new Cliente()
    {
        Nombre = txtClienteNombre.Text.Trim(),
        Cedula = txtClienteCedula.Text.Trim(),
        Status = Status.Activo
    };
    context.Cliente.Add(cliente);
}
else
{
    cliente = ClienteActual;
    context.Cliente.Attach(cliente);
}
```

De ésta forma te aseguras que no se llaman ambos métodos.

Por otro lado, si agregas un item a una colección que pertenece a una clave foránea, no es necesario cargar el item en la otra parte de la relación:

```
CabeceraFactura cabeceraFactura = new CabeceraFactura()
{
    Cliente = cliente // esta forma
};
cliente.CabeceraFactura.Add(cabeceraFactura); // o esta forma
```

Las 2 provocan lo mismo, pero solo una es necesaria. EF va a cargar la otra parte automáticamente.

Como último comentario, ya que usas EF6, deberías ver de usar `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` y programación asincrónica.

Comment: El problema radicaba en que no puedes agregar un objeto que pertenece a otro contexto, aqui dejo el codigo corregido:

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que no puedes agregar una entidad a un contexto cuando pertenece a otro contexto, aqui el codigo corregido:

```
using(Context context = new Context())
        {
            Cliente cliente;
            if (clienteActual != consumidorFinal)
            {
                if (checkBoxNuevo.Checked)
                {
                    cliente = new Cliente()
                    {
                        Nombre = txtClienteNombre.Text.Trim(),
                        Cedula = txtClienteCedula.Text.Trim(),
                        Status = Status.Activo
                    };
                    context.Cliente.Add(cliente);
                }
                else
                {
                    cliente = context.Cliente.Where(c => c.Id == ClienteActual.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cliente = context.Cliente.Where(c => c.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            CabeceraFactura cabeceraFactura = new CabeceraFactura()
            {
                Fecha = DateTime.Today,
                Status = Status.Activo,
                Cliente = cliente
            };
            decimal total = 0;
            foreach (DetalleFactura entry in detalleFacturaBindingSource)
            {
                total += (entry.PrecioUnitario * entry.Cantidad);
                cabeceraFactura.DetalleFactura.Add(new DetalleFactura() {
                    IdProducto = entry.IdProducto,
                    Cantidad = entry.Cantidad,
                    PrecioUnitario = entry.PrecioUnitario,
                    Subtotal = entry.Subtotal,
                    Status = Status.Activo
                });
            }
            cabeceraFactura.Total = total;
            cabeceraFactura.IdCliente = cliente.Id;
            context.CabeceraFactura.Add(cabeceraFactura);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```